# Release management causing build to fail

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, release-management, ms-release-management

I'm trying to configure release management to run with our TFS. Upon building I get an exception and cannot work out how to fix it:

Exception Message: Release build failed (type Exception)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

The releases do not appear on the release management client. So i can only assume it cant reach the release management server? Is there anyway to get more debug information?

I cant find much information on this?

Comment: In your build output, click on 'View Log' to get more information about the failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what Wouter said (Hi Wouter! :)):

1. Make sure the Release Management **client** is installed on your build **agent**. Once it's installed, make sure you've run it and connected it to your RM server. The account you do this as does not matter.
2. Make sure the **Build service account** (the account that all of your builds run as) is a **Service User** in Release Management.

Comment: Hi this fixed my problem thanks. The Release management client has become disconnected to the release management server. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear! Don't forget to accept this answer if it turned out to be the correct solution. Accepting an answer will help future people with the same problem find a solution more easily.

Answer (score 4):

To find out what;s causing the error you can edit your Build Definition and then disable the Release trigger. Then make sure your builds succeeds.

If the build succeeds without triggering a release, you can start a manual release from the RM Client and then select the latest build output that you just created.

This way, you can track the details of your release.

If both succeed, it could be that the account you're running your builder under doesn't have permissions to trigger a release in RM. You should check the account and make sure it can execute tasks on behalf of others.

Comment: i just change release as false under process tab in MS Build definition, then it was build successfully, then just start deployment by RM Client. its successfully deployed app. its working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Release build failed (type Exception)** happened to me while checking-in one single project. Since the rest of them would check-in fine, I discarded anything related with RM client or any of that.

The real reason was, a step in my release configuration not being able to complete. This project is a windows service, and that service is supposed to start at the end of the deployment process. But the service was crashing at the very first line of code, so it didn't started, and the release was failing. Very tricky, I was onnly able to see it by reading the logs in Release Management.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you change to the vNext release templates. It does not require customisation of the build template as it listens instead to build events.

In 2013.4 you can configure the vNext template. I have a blog post on how to configure the bits: http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

While I am using VSO and Azure servers for the demo, everything can run locally with 2013.4.